# Yii urlManager - Dynamic controller name

Tags: php, yii

I don't know if this is possible with Yii's urlManager, but I have urls like:

```
http://example.com/district/group/search
http://example.com/district/report/total
http://example.com/district/user/manage
```

I want to route something like:

```
'district/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'district<controller>/<action>'
```

So that it calls `DistrictGroupController@actionSearch` or `DistrictReportController@actionTotal` or `DistrictUserController@actionManage` respectively.

Is there any way to do this universally with the urlManager, or do I need to do each controller independently (`district/search/<action:\w+>'=>'districtSearch/<action>'`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That works for me:

```
'<prefix:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<prefix><controller>/view',
'<prefix:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<prefix><controller>/<action>',
```

( :D I expect isn't to late )

Comment: Perfect, I had 30 lines of config and was planning on 60 more for the application I am working on, so this just saved me a ton.  Thanks!